# Profile doesn't match the entitlements file's value for the com.apple.application-identifier entitlement

Tags: xcode, macos, code-signing, provisioning-profile, code-signing-entitlements

*I know there are already a lot of posts about this error, but I could'nt figure out a way to fix my specific situation*.

I have trouble validating/distributing a macOS application from the Xcode Organizer. When Xcode asks me to choose provisioning profiles it shows me this error:

> Profile doesn't match the entitlements file's value for the com.apple.application-identifier entitlement.

[image]

StockMonitor.app has a "Copy files" build phase to move Launcher.app bundle to a subfolder.

[image]

In Xcode the provisioning profiles looks correct

[image]

When I check the entitlements from the command line after archiving I can see that for whatever reason the Launcher.app got the identifier from StockMonitor.app.

```
❯ codesign -d --entitlements - Launcher.app/
Executable=/Users/lukas/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2022-05-23/StockMonitor 23.05.22, 14.55.xcarchive/Products/Applications/StockMonitor.app/Contents/Library/LoginItems/Launcher.app/Contents/MacOS/Launcher
[Dict]
    [Key] com.apple.application-identifier
    [Value]
        [String] UE4U5XA7R9.de.lukaswuerzburger.stock-monitor
    [Key] com.apple.developer.team-identifier
    [Value]
        [String] UE4U5XA7R9
    [Key] com.apple.security.app-sandbox
    [Value]
        [Bool] true
    [Key] com.apple.security.application-groups
    [Value]
        [Array]
            [String] group.UE4U5XA7R9.de.lukaswuerzburger.stock-monitor.settings
    [Key] com.apple.security.cs.disable-library-validation
    [Value]
        [Bool] true
    [Key] com.apple.security.files.user-selected.read-only
    [Value]
        [Bool] true
    [Key] com.apple.security.network.client
    [Value]
        [Bool] true
```

The entitlement file is here:

[image]

The build settings are like this:

[image]

It looks like Xcode takes the entitlements from StockMonitor.app and overrides the entitlements of Launcher.app. The question is how to prevent that.

Comment: Could you please describe your build pipeline a bit more? 
I think it should be so: you build the inner app, you sign the inner app with the release signature, you build the outer app without sign, you copy the signed inner app to the subdirectory of built outer app, you sign the outer app, done.
You could also go to the build output and take a look what xcodebuild and sign commands are applied, and attach them to the question.

Comment: https://www.ottorinobruni.com/how-to-fix-error-profile-doesnt-match-the-entitlements-files-values-for-the-application-identifier-and-keychain-access-groups-entitlements/